# Auto check a checkbox if highlighted over 1

Tags: jquery

This is what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/HsVZR/

What I wish to accomplish is when you start to highlight the td's red, I would like to auto check the checkboxes at the right.

So when theres >= 1 .highlightRed in a tr, it should auto check the checkbox. If it goes == 0 it should uncheck the checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/HsVZR/2/

Two things that needs to be done is the correct if statement so it counts the .highlightRed in the current parent , and so it checks / unchecks <- I dont know how to select the checkbox, tried:

```
$(this).parent('tr').child('td').find('.removalbox').attr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.editable').live('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlightRed');
        $(this).parent('tr').find('.removalbox').attr('checked',$(this).parent().find('td.highlightRed').length >0);
    });
});​
```

On and by the way, .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on().

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HsVZR/11/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HsVZR/8/ If you try to select three columns at the bottom and one at the top row, then try to unmark them all, the last row's checkbox is kept checked while nothing is marked

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you are looking for:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('td.editable').live('click', function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('highlightRed');

                if( $(this).parent('tr').find('.highlightRed').length >= 1 )
                {
                    $(this).parent('tr').find('.removalbox').attr('checked','checked');
                }else{
                    $(this).parent('tr').find('.removalbox').removeAttr('checked');
                }


            });
        }); ​
```

Comment: @Karem not sure why this wouldn't be working - works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/lelandrichardson/HsVZR/12/ what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HsVZR/15/

```
$(this).parent('tr').find(".removalbox").attr("checked", $(this).parent('tr').find('td.highlightRed').length >= 1);
```

Also, you shouldn't use so long jQuery-statements to find elements on your pages. Assign proper class names or IDs to your elements block-wise — you always will be able to access them as simple as `$('myblock-properclass')`.

Checking/unchecking checkbox can be easily done with

```
$('.removalbox').live('click', function()
{ 
    this.checked == true ? $(this).parents('tr').find('td.editable').addClass('highlightRed') : $(this).parents('tr').find('td.editable').removeClass('highlightRed');       
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's more than one row and since the OP is using a table I'd assume there is more than one.

Comment: I'm having many rows, just tried the marking works but the checkbox checking/unchecking doesnt work

Comment: @j08691, then it should be clarified within the post. I fixed my code.